# What is the meaning of number that setTimeout returns

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Usually you assign a setTimeout to a variable, if you want to cancel the timeout later.

I've wrote a simple setTimeout in console, and to my surprise, the console returned a number. What is the meaning of this number?

```
<< setTimeout(function(data){console.log(data)},2000,"data passed as arg");
>> 114
```

Comment: [Here ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), I'm just wondering ... "_This question does not show any research effort ..._", or the old good "RTFM".

Comment: my bad, google was vague, but never explicitly searched the docs

Comment: Well, I didn't vote down, the question is clear = ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [timer identifier](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html), that allows you to cancel it later

```js
const a = setTimeout (console.log, 1000, 'hello A')
const b = setTimeout (console.log, 1000, 'hello B')
clearTimeout (a)
// you won't see 'hello A', because it was canceled
// you will only see 'hello B'
```

It works for `setInterval` and `clearInterval` too

```js
const t = setInterval (console.log, 1000, 'hello world')
setTimeout (clearInterval, 5000, t)
// outputs 'hello world' once per second
// 5 seconds later, the interval timer is canceled
```

Comment: The second example works, but to quote the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout): "*`clearTimeout()` and `clearInterval()` can technically be used interchangeably. For clarity, however, you should try to always match them to avoid confusion when maintaining your code.*"

Comment: @Herohtar wups, I did intend to use the proper one. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4):

It's an identifier for the timer. You can pass it to `clearTimeout()` to cancel the operation.